# android:Why "layout_weight=1" makes the view align parent bottom in linearlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

The xml layout is like this:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bottom"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And it turns out that the textview will be placed to the bottom of its parent.I think layout_weight is used to allocate unusesd space and it's very common to use layout_weight with code like :

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
```

But in this case,the first layout asks to occupy all spaces with:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent
```

So how does layout weight work here?
PS:I have read this question:   [What does android:layout_weight mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean) but I don't think it accounts for this question.

> layout_weight specifies how much of the extra space in the layout to be allocated to the View.

The first linearlayout has already taken the whole space with attribute match_parent,why setting layout_weight enables the second view to showup at the bottom ?
I believe this is not the common usage of layout_weight.Hope somebody point out my mistake.

Comment: when you use layout_weight  make layout_widht = '0dp' in horizontal orientation and make layout_height= '0dp' in vertical orientation

Answer (score 1):

When you use `layout_weight` attribute it is used to calculate the weightage of child views of the single parent.

As you have not mentioned weight of all other views it's behaving wrong.

`layout_weight` is useful when you want your child views to be certain percentage of the parent view.

for example,

in parent view you need to mention:

```
android:weightSum="1"
```

So your parent view will have total weight as 1, and in both of the views you need to mention the:

`android:layout_weight=".9"` and `android:layout_weight=".1"`

so the first view will take 90%, and second view will take 10% of the space.

To be more clear Ideally the sum of weights of all the childs should be equal to the `weightsum` mentioned in parent, to it work as expected.

**And as you have provided `android:layout_width,`android:layout_height` of the textview, this is the mistake as it will make issue in the weight.

So to use weight attribute correctly you need to give other specs as `0dp` in order to weight to apply successfully.**

> Note: When you use weight other specs like `android:layout_width,
>   android:layout_height` should be set to `0dp`.
>
> To understand it practically, why don't you play around with below
>   layout:
>
> Just Try to change the weight of linear_layout, text_view and you will see, how it's supposed to works ideally:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="bottom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I understand the common use of layout_weight.What I intend to do at the beginning is to place the textview at the bottom of a linearlayout.The layout I posted in the question can achieve this goal.I am just wondering if someone can explain how it works.

Comment: i tried to explain the mistake, in the answer please read it and let me know if you still have any doubts, i would be glad to help you!! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place your components in separate boxes in layout ,you should use `LinearLayout`.
 You can define **the manner of boxes place** with `orientation` *vertical* or *horizental*.
You can define **their size** easily with `layout_weight`.
look here:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id=@+id/parent_linear>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4">
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="bottom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

`parent_linear` divides your layout in 2 parts(because you use 2 components) vertically. Now you can set weights to child's components width. So,(for TextView) you set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for its width and `android:layout_weight="2"` ..*follow it for LinearLayout*- . 
The result of this is *parent_layout* divide itself into 6 parts (2+4=6),and  allocates 4 parts to LinearLayout and 2 for TextView.